# Projecting points from 4d-space into 3d-space in Mathematica

Tags: geometry, wolfram-mathematica, polyhedra

Suppose we have a set of points with the restriction that for each point all coordinates are non-negative, and the sum of coordinates is equal to 1. This restricts points to lie in a 3-dimensional simplex so it makes sense to try to map it back into 3 dimensional space for visualization.

The map I'm looking for would take extreme points (1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0) and (0,0,0,1) to vertices of "nicely positioned" regular tetrahedron. In particular, center of the tetrahedron will be at the origin, one vertex would lie on the z axis, one face to parallel to x,y plane, and one edge to be parallel to x axis.

Here's code that does similar thing for points in 3 dimensions, but it doesn't seem obvious how to extend it to 4. Basically I'm looking for 4-d equivalents of functions tosimplex (which takes 4 dimensions into 3) and it's inverse fromsimplex

```
A = Sqrt[2/3] {Cos[#], Sin[#], Sqrt[1/2]} & /@ 
    Table[Pi/2 + 2 Pi/3 + 2 k Pi/3, {k, 0, 2}] // Transpose;
B = Inverse[A];
tosimplex[{x_, y_, z_}] := Most[A.{x, y, z}];
fromsimplex[{u_, v_}] := B.{u, v, Sqrt[1/3]};

(* checks *)
extreme = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
Graphics[Polygon[tosimplex /@ extreme]]
fromsimplex[tosimplex[#]] == # & /@ extreme
```

**Answer:**

straightforward reformulation of deinst's answer in terms of matrices gives following. (1/sqrt[4] comes up as 4th coordinate because it's the distance to simplex center)

```
A = Transpose[{{-(1/2), -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6])), 
     1/Sqrt[4]}, {1/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])), -(1/(2 Sqrt[6])), 
     1/Sqrt[4]}, {0, -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])) + Sqrt[3]/2, -(1/(2 Sqrt[6])), 
     1/Sqrt[4]}, {0, 0, Sqrt[2/3] - 1/(2 Sqrt[6]), 1/Sqrt[4]}}];
B = Inverse[A];
tosimplex[{x_, y_, z_, w_}] := Most[A.{x, y, z, w}];
fromsimplex[{t_, u_, v_}] := B.{t, u, v, 1/Sqrt[4]};

(* Checks *)
extreme = Table[Array[Boole[# == i] &, 4], {i, 1, 4}];
Graphics3D[Sphere[tosimplex[#], .1] & /@ extreme]
fromsimplex[tosimplex[#]] == # & /@ extreme
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want

```
   (1,0,0,0) -> (0,0,0)
   (0,1,0,0) -> (1,0,0)
   (0,0,1,0) -> (1/2,sqrt(3)/2,0)
   (0,0,0,1) -> (1/2,sqrt(3)/6,sqrt(6)/3))
```

And it is a linear transformation so you transform

```
   (x,y,z,w) - > (y + 1/2 * (z + w), sqrt(3) * (z / 2 + w / 6), sqrt(6) * w / 3)
```

**Edit**  You want the center at the origin -- just subtract the average of the four points.  Sorry

```
(1/2, sqrt(3)/6, sqrt(6) / 12)
```

Comment: Practice.  There is half a page of scrawled drawings of triangles etc.  The only tricky part is the height of the tetrahedron, and once you get the center of the base, it is just algebra.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

1. Generate four (non-orthoganal) 3-vectors, `\vec{v}_i` from the center of the tetrahedron toward each vertex.
2. For each four position `x = (x_1 .. x_4)` form the vector sum `\Sum_i x_i*\vec{v}_i`.

---

Of course this mapping is not unique in general, but you condition that the `x_i`'s sum to 1 constrains things.

Comment: care to venture a guess how to get coordinates of 4 vectors from the center of the tetrahedron towards each vertex? ;)